# How can I connect GitHub actions with AWS deployments without using a secret key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to be able to use GitHub Actions to be able to deploy resources with AWS, but without using a hard-coded user.

I know that it's possible to create an IAM user with a fixed credential, and that can be exported to GitHub Secrets, but this means if the key ever leaks I have a large problem on my hands, and rotating such keys are challenging if forgotten.

Is there any way that I can enable a password-less authentication flow for deploying code to AWS?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is possible now that GitHub have released their [Open ID Connector for use with GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services). You can configure the Open ID Connector as an Identity Provider in AWS, and then use that for an access point to any role(s) that you wish to enable. You can then configure the action to use the credentials acquired for the duration of the job, and when the job is complete, the credentials are automatically revoked.

To set this up in AWS, you need to create an Open Identity Connect Provider using the [instructions at AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html) or using a Terraform file similar to the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "github" {
  url = "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
  client_id_list = [
    // original value "sigstore",
    "sts.amazonaws.com", // Used by aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials
  ]
  thumbprint_list = [
    // original value "a031c46782e6e6c662c2c87c76da9aa62ccabd8e",
    "6938fd4d98bab03faadb97b34396831e3780aea1",
  ]
}
```

The client id list is the 'audience' which is used to access this content -- you can vary that, provided that you vary it in all the right places. The thumbprint is a hash/certificate of the Open ID Connector, and `6938...aea1` is the current one used by GitHub Actions -- you can calculate/verify the value by [following AWS' instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc_verify-thumbprint.html). The `thumbprint_list` can hold up to 5 values, so newer versions can be appended when they are being made available ahead of time while continuing to use older ones.

If you're interested in where this magic value came from, you can find out at [How can I calculate the thumbprint of an OpenID Connect server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69247498/how-can-i-calculate-the-thumbprint-of-an-openid-connect-server/69247499#69247499)

Once you have enabled the identity provider, you can use it to create one or more custom roles (replacing  with :

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
resource "aws_iam_role" "github_alblue" {
  name = "GitHubAlBlue"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
      Effect = "Allow"
      Principal = {
        Federated = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
      }
      Condition = {
        StringLike = {
          "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud" :  ["sts.amazonaws.com" ],
          "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub" : "repo:alblue/*"
        }
      }
    }]
  })
}
```

You can create as many different roles as you need, and even split them up by audience (e.g. 'production', 'dev'). Provided that the OpenID connector's audience is trusted by the account then you're good to go. (You can use this to ensure that the OpenID Connector in a Dev account doesn't trust the roles in a production account and vice-versa.) You can have, for example, a read-only role for performing `terraform validate` and then another role for `terraform apply`.

The subject is passed from GitHub, but looks like:

```
repo:<organization>/<repository>:ref:refs/heads/<branch>
```

There may be different formats that come out later. You could have an action/role specifically for PRs if you use `:ref:refs/pulls/*` for example, and have another role for `:ref:refs/heads/production/*`.

The final step is getting your GitHub Actions configured to use the token that comes back from the AWS/OpenID Connect:

**Standard Way**

```
jobs:
  terraform-validate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Configure AWS credentials from Test account
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@master
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:role/GitHubAlBlue
          aws-region: us-east-1
      - name: Display Identity
        run: aws sts get-caller-identity
```

**Manual Way**

What's actually happening under the covers is something like this:

```
jobs:
  terraform-validate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE: .git/aws.web.identity.token.file
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-west-2
      AWS_ROLE_ARN: arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:role/GitHubAlBlue
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Configure AWS
        run: |
          sleep 3 # Need to have a delay to acquire this
          curl -H "Authorization: bearer $ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" \
            "$ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL&audience=sts.amazonaws.com" \
            | jq -r '.value' > $AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
          aws sts get-caller-identity
```

You need to ensure that your `AWS_ROLE_ARN` is the same as defined in your AWS account, and that the audience is the same as accepted by the OpenID Connect and the Role name as well.

Essentially, there's a race condition between the job starting, and the token's validity which doesn't come in until after GitHub has confirmed the job has started; if the size of the `AWS_WEB_IDENITY_TOKEN_FILE` is less than 10 chars, it's probably an error and sleep/spinning will get you the value afterwards.

The name of the `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE` doesn't really matter, so long as it's consistent. If you're using docker containers, then storing it in e.g. `/tmp` will mean that it's not available in any running containers. If you put it under `.git` in the workspace, then not only will git ignore it (if you're doing any hash calculations) but it will also be present in any other docker run actions that you do later on.

You might want to configure your role so that the validity of the period used is limited; once you have the web token it's valid until the end of the job, but the token requested has a lifetime of 15 minutes, so it's possible for a longer-running job to expose that.

It's likely that GitHub will have a blog post on how to configure/use this in the near future. The above information was inspired by https://awsteele.com/blog/2021/09/15/aws-federation-comes-to-github-actions.html, who has some examples in CloudFormation templates if that's your preferred thing.

**Update** GitHub (accidentally) [changed their thumbprint](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-13-github-actions-update-on-oidc-based-deployments-to-aws/) and the example has been updated. See for more information. The new thumbprint is `6938fd4d98bab03faadb97b34396831e3780aea1` but it's possible to have multiple thumbprints in the IAM OpenID connector.

Comment: I started adding the information about how to calculate the thumbprint into this question, but it went into too much detail and may have dissuaded people reading it, so I added it as another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69247498/how-can-i-calculate-the-thumbprint-of-an-openid-connect-server/69247499#69247499

Comment: Can you clarify the possible values for client_id_list in the OIDC provider? I see Aidan used the repo name (which works for me), while you used "githubactions". I'd like to scope it to the GitHub account, as I've done with the trust policy on my role.

Comment: Also, using a client_id_list of  "githubactions" I get an error:  

An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Incorrect token audience

Comment: You can use whatever you want, but you need to be consistent. It’s used three times; the OICD identity provider, the role’s trust, and the webid token url that you call with wget. Provided that you use the same one(s) consistently you should be able to use whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I didn't see the added query param in your `curl` call. I'm getting "Can't issue ID_TOKEN for audience 'githubactions'." if the audience is set to anything but the string "sigstore". It also works if I leave the param off.

Comment: Well the service is in beta; they might gave changed how the audience is described and passed through. Note there are two conditions here: one for the :sub(ject) and one for the :aud(ience) — the subject is the one that will have the repo name in it, so you can use that for scoping the result, regardless of what the audience is.

Comment: The problem is the OIDC provider's client_id_list. It must be specified (at least in the TF resource) and must match the audience. If you don't specify an audience of "sigstore", it will be set to the HTTPS repo URL as well. So looks like the choice is (1) don't specify an audience, keep a list of repos in your client_id_list, and filter at the OIDC level, or (2) use "sigstore" as the audience, add "sigstore" to the client_id_list, and don't filter at the OIDC level. Either way, you can filter in the trust policy as you stated. It's probably worth adding some of these details to the answer.

Comment: `curl -H "Authorization: bearer $ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" \
            "$ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL&audience=githubactions" \
            | jq -r '.value' > $AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE`

from where `ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN"` and `ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL` value is being fetched?

Comment: The ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN* variables are being supplied by the GitHub Actions runner.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, would you like to take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461997/how-to-use-serverless-framework-in-github-actions-using-github-actions-oidc-feat

i was trying you solutions and i am stuck with deploying serverless with this

Comment: After GitHub issue update, you no longer need `sigstore` in client_id_list and iam_role as well. The GHActions task would also not need `audience: sigstore`

Answer (score 1):

Github recently updated their certifcate chain and the thumprint has changed from the one mentioned above `a031c46782e6e6c662c2c87c76da9aa62ccabd8e` to `6938fd4d98bab03faadb97b34396831e3780aea1`

Github Issue: https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/issues/357

Answer (score -2):

For some reason I keep getting this with the provided answer of AlBlue:

> "message":"Can't issue ID_TOKEN for audience 'githubactions'."

Deploying the stack provided in [this post](https://awsteele.com/blog/2021/09/15/aws-federation-comes-to-github-actions.html), does work however.

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the existing answer than a new one, but this looks like your job doesn’t have the “permissions” section in the job configuration.

Comment: Please include relevant information from the link in your answer. The content of the link may change in the future which case your answer isn't useful anymore.

Comment: Thanks @AlBlue, but I couldnt due to the fact that I created an Stackoverflow account for this.
My job has the same permissions. Even using the cfn oidc provider&role, works.